# Magento 2 How to create simple module that echoes text on checkout success page?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks

I have tried all examples found on Magento forums but I can't make it work.

I need to get Order ID and customer email on checkout success page.

Here's my module structure:

TV2M/GoogleSurvey/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'TV2M_GoogleSurvey',
    __DIR__
);
```

TV2M/GoogleSurvey/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TV2M_GoogleSurvey" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

TV2M/GoogleSurvey/Block/Onepage/Success.php

```
<?php
namespace TV2M\GoogleSurvey\Block\Onepage;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;



class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    public function getGoogleSurvey()
    {
        return "my@email.com";
    }
}
```

Module is activated, setup upgrade, cache clean...

In my theme folder, I have created a phtml file called by layout XML. File is loaded correctly. But when I call my function it returns nothing: `echo $block->getEmail();`

I have also tried to add di.xml:

TV2M/GoogleSurvey/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="TV2M\GoogleSurvey\Block\Onepage\Success" />
</config>
```

Can someone please tell me how to access getGoogleSurvey() function? Which files are necessary in my module? Thanks in advance.

Comment: another thing that should be recommended, is using the sequence inside your module.xml file, to define the loading order. This should not be the issue in this case, but since it depends on the checkout module, it should be placed inside the module sequence.

Answer (score 0):

you should run `di:compile command`, also pass require parameters in constructor of parent

> class(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success)

Also change `getEmail()` function name it will be good in practice because we also access DB field by getEmail().

You should have call that template file with your current block in layout file. Can you please share the layout code?

Comment: You do not need to implement the constructor in the extended class, if you dont change any constructor parameters.

Comment: I've changed function name to getGoogleSurvey() it's not working. Why should I run di:compile I'm in developer mode?

Comment: @TzV It is good practice to run di:compile if we add something into di.xml or constructor. Anyways, Is your block is calling? You can check with enabling template and block hints. Can you provide your layout xml code?

Comment: Thank's for your feedback. But no output. 
My XML is correct as it calls the phtml file in my theme folder:

`<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="google_servey.body" after="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/google_survey.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>`

And there google_survey.phtml:

`<?php echo $block->getGoogleSurvey(); ?>

Hello`

I just get the Hello.

Why should I need di.xml?
Can someone provide my with the files I really need just to output something from a block file in module? On any page.

Comment: My block is called:

/home/webmaster/public_html/dev/app/design/frontend/TV2M/KarineJeff_v2/Magento_Theme/templates/html/google_survey.phtml > 
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

But the class is called by another block I didn't edit:

/home/webmaster/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/button.phtml > 
TV2M\GoogleSurvey\Block\Onepage\Success

Comment: <referenceContainer name="before.body.end"> <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="google_servey.body" after="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/google_survey.phtml" /> </referenceContainer>
You should pass your block's class path in class parameter not of core. 
Also, you can type die('test'); and check by ctrl+u.

Answer (score 0):

first you have a problem in your

> TV2M/GoogleSurvey/Block/Onepage/Success.php

you defined namespace two times change file to this

```
<?php
namespace TV2M\GoogleSurvey\Block\Onepage;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return "my@email.com";
    }
}
```

if helps accept answer

Comment: You're right for namespace, but it's just a wrong copy and paste. I have edited my question with your code, it's not working either.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: No error, no output.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found by myself.

In google_survey.phtml the correct code to call the function getGoogleSurvey() is:

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('TV2M\GoogleSurvey\Block\Onepage\Success');
echo $blockObj->getGoogleSurvey();
```

For the entire module to work we need the files mentioned above:

> TV2M/GoogleSurvey/registration.php
>
> TV2M/GoogleSurvey/etc/module.xml
>
> TV2M/GoogleSurvey/Block/Onepage/Success.php

And in theme folder:

> templates/html/google_survey.phtml
>
> layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

Now I can change the function getGoogleSurvey() in order to get customer email:

```
$order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
return $order->getCustomerEmail()
```

We don't need di.xml in this case.

Thanks to those who spent time to help me.